# Can a program read text and analyze it for follow up questions?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence

I just held a conversation with a guy that claim that he developed an application that can provide answers to a written text. He says that any text that a human can read and understand, so does his application. Since I'm not in the world of AI or NLP, I just wonder if it's doable that a computer will analyze the following text and answer the question at the end:

> I have few transactions with me, so it goes like this: Transaction 1000 for the amount of $200 was canceled and the customer will pay $30 cancelation penalty. Transaction 1001 was approved for 300 USD. Transaction 1001 for the amount of $500 was voided but the customer was willing to pay $20 as CP (instead of 50).

From what he claims, his program can answer any question such as:

> how much money did we make for Cancelation Penalty (which should come to 30+20=50)

Is this doable?

Comment: Doable? Yea. Trivial? No.  Is he lying or exaggerating? Probably. You can see a video of IBM's Watson playing(dominating) Jeopardy [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOpW5VN2j2Q).  Its quite impressive and fun to watch, but if I were you, the first thing I would have said to the man is, "Well lets see this incredible, possibly-worth-millions-of-dollars piece of software you've got!"  But maybe thats just me.

Comment: Full understanding of a text written in natural language is an AI-complete problem. The guy you mentioned achieved what thousands of talented researchers are struggling with. Congratulations :) More seriously, he should test his system on real-world data (eg http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/fabulous/5765071/No-Diet-Diet-summer-slim-down.html).

Comment: You can make anything work for a very limited scope. So it's totally possible that his software does what he claims for the given example, but it will fail if the problem domain changes (or even the style in which the sentences are written).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an active area of research ([a recent PhD thesis on a related topic](http://technologies.kmi.open.ac.uk/poweraqua/thesis-master-viva.pdf)). The short answer is NO. Doing so would likely imply having to implement a [strong AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence).

Nevertheless, the problem has gained on popularity in recent years. You are probably familiar with Apple's Siri (which is in fact one of the outcomes of [one of the biggest AI project in history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CALO)), and Google's Google Now and you know how limited they are (definitely not for the lack of effort).

There is also the [Watson system by IBM](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/) which is able to play the game Jeopardy better than any human player. IBM is currently aggressively investing into the technology (billions of dollars, new centers, hiring a lot).

For many years, there even have been attempts at implementing systems focused on exactly the kind of question answering that you described: factual, constrained to a domain, a bit like exercises for highschool kids.

The most prominent examples are:

- the [Project ARISTO](http://www.allenai.org/TemplateGeneric.aspx?contentId=8) of the [Allen institute for Artificial Intelligence](http://www.allenai.org/Default.aspx) (funded by Microsoft's co-founder Paul Allen), see [the list of their ARISTO-related papers](http://www.allenai.org/TemplateGeneric.aspx?contentId=12).
- the [Cyc project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyc) - a large knowledge base of common-sense facts
- [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) - this one is aimed more at general factual question answering based on curated data sets

The ARISTO project originated out of the [HALO project](http://web.archive.org/web/20111001051321/http://www.projecthalo.com/Default.htm) (funded by Vulcan, which is Paul Allen's investment company):

> Project Halo is a staged, long-range research effort by Vulcan Inc.
>   towards the development of a "Digital Aristotle"—a reasoning system
>   capable of answering novel questions and solving advanced problems in
>   a broad range of scientific disciplines and related human affairs. The
>   project focuses on creating two primary functions: a tutor capable of
>   instructing and assessing students in those subjects, and a research
>   assistant with broad, interdisciplinary skills to help scientists and
>   others in their work.

To that end, they [conducted a competition in 2004](http://web.archive.org/web/20130704072325/http://projecthalo.com/halotempl.asp?cid=21) with the following challenge:

> Each team was given four months to independently encode 50 pages out
>   of a chemistry syllabus into their respective KRR technology
>   platforms. At the end of this time, all the systems were sequestered
>   and a challenge exam consisting of 100 mostly novel questions was
>   released to the teams.
>
> The teams had two weeks to translate the questions into their
>   respective formal logical languages. These translations were run as
>   batch jobs on the systems, which produced documents containing English
>   answers and justifications.
>
> The final step was an impartial evaluation conducted by three separate
>   chemistry professors, who graded the “exams” for accuracy and
>   justification quality.

There were three competing teams: Cycorp (Austin, Texas), SRI International (Menlo Park, California), and Ontoprise (Karlsruhe, Germany).

The average score on the exam was about 40% to 47% correct. The average cost to translate text into the formal notation was around $10,000 per page (!).

[Vulcan's final report.](http://web.archive.org/web/20060318043806/http://www.projecthalo.com/content/docs/halopilot_vulcan_finalreport.pdf)

[The Seattle Times - Vulcan project aims to build 'Digital Aristotle'](http://seattletimes.com/html/businesstechnology/2001856160_halo12.html)

Granted this was 10 years ago and there was some progress since then (perhaps most notably Watson), but we are still nowhere near even domain-focused factual general question answering.

Comment: thanks for sharing this knowledge. I was under the impression I was about to lose my job ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's possible that an AI program can parse this text and understand this particular question, but the claim that it can understand **any** human-readable text is just preposterous.

As others commented, this problem is a huge research effort ongoing for decades with no final solution in sight, and this guy should be rich and world-famous if it actually were to work. But you should keep an eye on him, so that you can destroy his research in time lest skynet finally takes over.

Answer (score 0):

General questions are hard, but if you limit it to algebra problems it might be easier. See this: http://people.csail.mit.edu/regina/my_papers/wp.pdf